# Windows Phone 8.1 UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8.1, azure-blob-storage, unhandled-exception

```
 List<Person> friends = new List<Person>();
            StorageCredentials credential = new StorageCredentials(x, x);
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credential, true);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("cryptochat");
```

When creating the blob client at "CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();" application break and enter here:

```
 #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

The exception is: `{"The argument 'ParallelOperationThreadCount' is larger than maximum of '64'\r\nParameter name: ParallelOperationThreadCount"}`
This code was working in visual studio 2013 then I reinstalled windows 10 and installed 2015 now it does not work.  And this code works on emulator but not on device.

Comment: what's the exception and the stacktrace?

Comment: It does not give a specific exception the actual problem is that otherwise I could solve it :) It throws from program suddenly after entering here : #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif  @thumbmunkeys

Comment: the exception has a type, eg. `NullReferenceException`, the type is important to analyze the issue

Comment: The interesting thing is that it does not give any type even an exception windows it just throw user from app but only on device code does not work. on emulator everything is fine @thumbmunkeys

Comment: This is call stack when it breaks:
> CryptoChat.ni.EXE!CryptoChat.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__7_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 50 C#

Comment: when I press continue at break it throws from app without any warning @thumbmunkeys

Comment: the variable `e` contains an `ExceptionObject` the type of that object is important

Comment: {"The argument 'ParallelOperationThreadCount' is larger than maximum of '64'\r\nParameter name: ParallelOperationThreadCount"} @thumbmunkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/384), try updating your azure SDK

Comment: It still does not work same errors and "blobClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 1;" is green underlined :"CloudBlobClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount is obsolete:use DefaultRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount" when I try suggestion still same error continues

Comment: @Thomas a mistake, I thought it was mine, as it was nearly identical to mine